# I want to access Images which is outside of the server

Tags: asp.net, image, server.mappath, imagehandler

I'm gonna implement this on asp.net and my problem is I have some images in some others folder i can access those in run command in from windows explorer but i need to put those images to WEB and browse them automatically.

But i tried to do it it wont work because the images are outside of the server..how to do it? is there is a possibility of doing this?

Think of a small LAN Network and when you browse the web your friends specific location data should be display can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS you can add Virtual Directory to your website and point it to network location of where the images are stored.

[Here are instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).